# I have large file contents that I want to make searchable on AWS CloudSearch but the maximum document size is 1MB - how do I deal with this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I could split the file contents up into separate search documents but then I would have to manually identify this in the results and only show one result to the user - otherwise it will look like there are 2 files that match their search when in fact there is only one.

Also the relevancy score would be incorrect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the response from AWS support was to split the files up into separate documents. In response to my concerns regarding relevancy scoring and multiple hits they said the following:

> You do raise two very valid concerns here for your more challenging use case here. With regard to relevance, you face a very significant problem already in that is harder to establish a strong 'signal' and degrees of differentiation with large bodies of text. If the documents you have are much like reports or whitepapers, a potential workaround to this may be in indexing the first X number of characters (or the first identified paragraph) into a "thesis" field. This field could be weighted to better indicate what the document subject matter may be without manual review.
>
> With regard to result duplication, this will require post-processing on your end if you wish to filter it. You can create a new field that can generate a unique "Parent" id that will be shared for each chunk of the whole document. The post-processing can check to see if this "Parent" id has already been return(the first result should be seen as most relevant), and if it has, filter the subsequent results. What is doubly useful in such a scenario, is that you include a refinement link into your results that could filter on all matches within that particular Parent id.